# C++ primer 5 ed. Overloaded Functions and User-Defined Conversion

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, conversion-operator

Hello I am at chapter 14 in C++ primer 5 ed. I've understood anything from previous chapters. It is really a very good book. however when I've reached this, it is a bit ambiguous for me:

> "In a call to an overloaded function, if two (or more) user-defined conversions provide a viable match, the conversions are considered equally good. The rank of any standard conversions that might or might not be required is not considered. Whether a built-in conversion is also needed is considered only if the overload set can be
>   matched using the same conversion function.
>   For example, our call to `manip` would be ambiguous even if one of the classes defined a constructor that required a standard conversion for the argument:

```
struct E {
     E(double);
     // other members
};
void manip2(const C&);
void manip2(const E&);
// error ambiguous: two different user defined conversions could be used
manip2(10); // manip2(C(10) or 
manip2(E(double(10)))
```

In this case, C has a conversion from int and `E` has a conversion from double. For the call `manip2(10)`, both `manip2` functions are viable:

• `manip2(const C&)` is viable because C has a converting constructor that takes an int. That constructor is an exact match for the argument.

• `manip2(const E&)` is viable because E has a converting constructor that takes a double and we can use a standard conversion to convert the int argument in order to use that converting constructor.

Because calls to the overloaded functions require different user-defined conversions from one another, this call is ambiguous. In particular, even though one of the calls requires a standard conversion and the other is an exact match, the compiler will still flag this call as an error.

Note In a call to an overloaded function, the rank of an additional standard conversion (if any) matters only if the viable functions require the same user-defined conversion. If different user-defined conversions are needed, then the call is ambiguous."

- Can someone explain the last paragraph with an example? Thank you!

Comment: @cigen Is this really a language-lawyer kind of question?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm on the fence about that actually. It's not a language lawyer question, in that there's no ambiguity in the wording here. On the other hand, it does require *some* amount of practice with standardese to parse *exactly* what is being said here. I'm hoping someone who watches this tag will be able to give a nice answer (with examples as asked for). This might not be an appropriate use of tags, so please feel free to remove the tag if you think so.